# Mailto with attachment from SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, mailto

I have report with email link like

```
="mailto:" & Fields!EmailAddress.Value
& "?subject=Test email"
& "&body=This is a test email"
```

Is there any way I can add attachment? I need to add a company logo.
I did research but couldn't find clear information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure an attachment is what you want? Or do you want to embed the company logo in the email?

Some email clients support an attachment method for mailto e.g.

```
&attachment="C:\fileName.txt"
```

or something similar